# Illegal start of simple expression creating a simple dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Apologies this is probably something very obvious. I don't understand why this isn't working:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame([("A",1),("B",2),("C",3)],["Letter","Number"])
```

When I run this I get the below error:

> error: illegal start of simple expression

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Pyspark syntax not Spark Scala. Try this instead:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3))).toDF("Letter", "Number")
```

Or:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3)).toDF("Letter", "Number")
```